# ThorsSQL Lib: Part 3: Layer 5 Request/Response

Tags: c++, c++11, mysql, c++14, stream

Have a working version of MySQL implementation of ThorsSQL library done.

If you want to check it out you can find the whole thing on [github ThorsSQL](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL/tree/ef508c463aded45dd1ce0605a907f41f589b76b4).

This is a follow on to previous code Reviews:
[Part 3: Layer 4](/q/158139/507)
[Part 3: Layer 3](/q/158113/507)
[Part 3: Layer 2](/q/158052/507)
[Part 3: Layer 1](/q/158007/507)
[Part 2](/q/94901/507)
[Part 1](/q/94899/507)

The [documentation for these classes is here](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL/tree/ef508c463aded45dd1ce0605a907f41f589b76b4/src/MySQL/ReadMe.md):

### Part 3 (Layer 5): Request/Response

Interaction with the SQL server is normally done via a `Request`/`Response` cycle. The client makes a request to the server and the server responds with a response packages.

So I abstracted these two different types of package.

The `RequPackage` base class has the abstract method `virtual  void build(ConectWriter& writer)       const = 0;`. This is called by the `ConectWriter` object to write the object onto the stream. So each specific child instance of `RequPackage` must understand how to write itself to the stream.

When we look on the stream for a response the first byte indicates the type of response message. Unfortunately some messages have the same first byte and we have to know what message was sent to understad that first byte.

This is why the `Connection::sendMessageGetResponse()` method takes an action map as a second parameter. When you call `sendMessageGetResponse()` you pass a map of valid byte codes to functors; these functors create the correct `RespPackage` child object from the stream. Note: Default response object are automatically handled.

Example:

```
connection.sendMessageGetResponse(
               RequPackagePrepare(statement),
               {{0x00, [](int firstByte, ConectReader& reader)
                        {return new RespPackagePrepare(firstByte, reader);}
                }
               }
           );
```

So all children of `RespPackage` must accept a `firstByte` and `ConectReader` object. They will then construct themselves reading the data directly from the stream.

### RequPackage.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_PACKAGE_REQU_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_PACKAGE_REQU_H

#include "ConectWriter.h"
#include "RequPackage.h"
#include "ThorSQL/SQLUtil.h"
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

class RequPackage
{
    std::string     humanMessage;
    public:
        RequPackage(std::string const& humanMessage, std::string const& requName)
            : humanMessage(humanMessage)
        {
            (void)requName;
        }
        virtual ~RequPackage()  {}
        virtual  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& s)   const = 0;
        virtual  void build(ConectWriter& writer)       const = 0;
        void send(ConectWriter& writer) const
        {
            this->build(writer);
            writer.flush();
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, RequPackage const& data)
        {
            return data.print(s)
                    << "humanMessage(" << data.humanMessage << ") ";
        }
};

    }
}

#endif
```

### RespPackage.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_PACKAGE_RESP_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_PACKAGE_RESP_H

#include "ThorSQL/SQLUtil.h"
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

class ConectReader;

class RespPackage
{
    protected:
        ConectReader&   reader;
        bool            ok;
        bool            error;
        bool            eof;
        std::string     humanMessage;
    public:
        RespPackage(ConectReader& reader, std::string const& respName)
            : reader(reader)
            , ok(false)
            , error(false)
            , eof(false)
        {
            (void)respName;
        }
        virtual ~RespPackage() {}
        virtual  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& s) const = 0;

        bool                isOK()              const                   {return ok;}
        bool                isError()           const                   {return error;}
        bool                isEOF()             const                   {return eof;}
        std::string const&  message()           const                   {return humanMessage;}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, RespPackage const& data)
        {
            return data.print(s)
                    << "humanMessage(" << data.humanMessage << ") ";
        }
};

template<typename To>
std::unique_ptr<To> downcastUniquePtr(std::unique_ptr<RespPackage>&& item);

    }
}

#ifndef COVERAGE_MySQL
#include "RespPackage.tpp"
#endif

#endif
```

## RespPackage.tpp

```
namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

template<typename To>
std::unique_ptr<To> downcastUniquePtr(std::unique_ptr<RespPackage>&& item)
{
    if (item.get() == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<To> result;
    // Note the dynamic_cast may fail and throw.
    // If this happens item retains ownership.
    try
    {
        result.reset(&dynamic_cast<To&>(*item));
    }
    catch (std::bad_cast const&)
    {
        throw std::domain_error("ThorsAnvil::SQL::downcastUniquePtr: Casting reponse to expected type failed");
    }
    // Now that ownership has been transferred.
    // Release the original pointer.
    item.release();

    return result;
}

    }
}
```